# 2d polygon orthographic projection on a plane of a 3d object

Tags: 3d, geometry, 2d, mesh, projection

I have a 3d object (a non-convex mesh made of triangles) and i need it's projection on the XZ plane, which would be a polygon, as if it had the shape of the object's orthographic shadow. Just need the boundary points, for some fast 2d collision check.

Any thoughts on how to find this polygon?

I dont need full precision on the points, so my best idea this far was to run a discrete scan of the object into a grid with raycasts, and then build the polygon from the grid points where the raycasts hit the object.

From there i'd run a polyline decimation code to reduce the ammount of points, since the grid could give me a lot more points than the polygon really needs.

So here's the code idea i had

1. Perform Raycasts with dx distance of each other against the mesh until we find a border point
2. Proceed to build the polygon points by following the border counter-clockwise with more raycasts untill we find the starting point again.
3. Run a polyline decimation code on the polygon

There must be some better way of doing this, am i missing something?
Is there a known algorithm / library for doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Just drop the *y*-coordinate of all your points: (*x,y,z*) => (*x,z*). Then run a border-tracing algorithm.

Comment: If your mesh has the topology of a surface, i.e. every edge shared by two (known) faces, it is enough to project (drop z) the edges shared by two faces having the z component of their normals with opposite sign. Only these can belong to the silhouette. If the body is convex, you are done. Otherwise you may have to discard a few internal edges.